# Count the number of nested child elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, count

I have the following xml (which is in fact a very simplified version of a FIX dictionary):

```
<fix>
<messages>
    <message name='Message1'>
        <field name='Field1' />
        <component name='Component1'/>
        <group name='Group1'>
            <field name='Field2' />
        </group>
    </message>
</messages>

<components>
    <component name='Component1'>
        <field name='Field3' />
        <group name='Group2' >
                <field name='Field4' />
                <group name='Group3' >
                    <field name='Field5' />
                    <component name='Component3' />
                </group>
        </group>
        <component name='Component2' /> 
    </component>
    <component name='Component2'>
        <field name='Field6' />
    </component>
    <component name='Component3'>
        <field name='Field7'/>
    </component>  

</components>
<fields>
    .....
</fields>
</fix>
```

Every message, component or group can have fields, components and groups.

I need to count the number of groups for every message. In the example above the number of groups for Message1 is 3 (Group1, Group2, Group3)

Comment: What have you already tried? Why result for `Message1` should be `3`? It contains 1 `group` only while other are descendants of `components`

Comment: Can you say if you can use XSLT 2.0 or above, or just XSLT 1.0?

Comment: @TimC I can use XSLT 2 or above, yes.

Comment: @Andersson Message1 has in its object graph 3 groups. It doesn’t matter where these groups are. This is the number I need to count. Will post later on what I’ve tried so far.

Comment: Thank you @TimC, works as expected. The tool is really useful!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you want to count the groups in referenced `component` elements, and further still, the `component` elements that are referenced in the first message may themselves reference other `component` elements with groups in.

In this case, a recursive function would do the trick.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:my="myFunctions">

  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="components" match="components/component" use="@name" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//message[@name='Message1']" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="message">
    <xsl:value-of select="my:groupCount(.)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="my:groupCount">
    <xsl:param name="node" />
    <xsl:value-of select="count($node//group) + sum($node//component/my:groupCount(key('components', @name)))" />
  </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMP

Actually, this would not give correct results in component1 and component2 both referenced component3 (which had groups in), as it would count the same group twice.

In this case, try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:my="myFunctions">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:key name="components" match="components/component" use="@name" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//message[@name='Message1']" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="message">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(my:groups(.)/@name)" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="my:groups">
    <xsl:param name="node" />
    <xsl:sequence select="$node//group, $node//component/my:groups(key('components', @name))" />
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Be wary of infinite loops if component1 referenced component2, but component2 referenced component1